# Python: Creating better rooms in text RPG with unique elements that change based on player actions

Tags: python

I am very new to coding and I'm probably biting off more than I can chew here, so please try to excuse my ignorance.

I am attempting to make a text based RPG in Python. My goal is to make something that isn't just a simple "choose your own adventure" story and actually has combat (set and random encounters) with a leveling system, shops, inns, and quests. It probably looks like a disgusting mess to anyone more experienced, but I do actually have everything working and the game is currently in a playable state (although the ending is still in progress).

Right now I am building all the rooms as functions like this:

```
 def generic_room():
  global enemy_spawn_set
  global spawn_rate
  path = '' 
  print(line101)
  while path == '':
  
        print("Make selection:")
        selc = (input().upper())

        if selc == "NORTH":
            print(line102)
            enemy_spawn_set = enemy_spawn? 
            spawn_rate = 3
            encounter_initiaiton()
            path = "?"
            print(f'\n{path}')
            generic_room_other2()
        
          
        .....


        elif selc == "EXPLORE":
            print(line103)

        elif selc == "HEAL" and p1.POTS > 0:
          .....
        
        elif selc == "HEAL" and p1.POTS == 0:
          print(f'{p1.name} is out of POTIONS and unable to heal at this time')      
    
        elif selc == "STATS":
          stat_check()
    
        elif selc == "HELP":
          world_menu()
    
        else:
          print('Please select a valid command or type HELP.\n')
```

Now most of the rooms have elements that are unique from each other. Some are intended to change their intro text when certain conditions are met (i.e. a key item found, boss defeated, ect.), some have NPC's with multiple lines of dialog that are affected by "inventory". Right now I have these conditions implemented as additional if/elif statements within the specific rooms function like this:

```
    .....
    elif selc == "EAST" and lantern == 0:
        print(line909)

    elif (selc == "EAST" and bear == 1) and lantern == 1:
        print(line914)
        boss_initiaiton0()
        bear = 0
        axe += 1
        print(line912b)
        path = "DEN 1"
        print(f'\n{path}')
        dungeon_cave1()

    elif (selc == "EAST" and bear == 0) and lantern == 1:
        print(line915)
        path = "DEN 1"
        print(f'\n{path}')
        dungeon_cave1()
    .....
```

Even though the game works, I was wondering if there would be a better way to do all this using classes/dictionaries?  I think I've found some good resources on how to build rooms like this, but in all of them the only thing that changes is the "items" located in these rooms.

Would it be possible to alter a room (made with classes/dictionaries) based on the events (like the ones I detailed above) that occur within?

Additionally, I have seen a number of text game tutorials that essentially build their worlds in the same way (using functions to define each room). Other than the code starting to look a little bloated as the game gets larger, is there a reason not to do this when it seems like the simplest/most straight forward method?

Thanks in advance for any assistance or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have found one of the reasons for the existance of object oriented programming... it's a way to structure code that makes the rules of the domain problem **explicit**. That means that the code is more readable, which means that in six months, after you took a break from your code and want to resume development, you won't hate yourself so much.

Classes are ways of bundling behavior of "generic" things of the problem domain -in this case, the way you want the game to be!

So you probably need a Room class, which specifies the generic behavior and properties of a Room. Writing classes you can create objects with variations of those attributes. Your global variables are probably attributes of some class. For example, *pots* sounds like an attribute of the *player* - because common sense guides us to think that it's something that is **had** by a player. That's how you build up OOP code - you think about the relationship of things and you model classes that reflect that understanding.

To give examples, the way I think about that in OOP is this- in pseudocode :

```
Class Player:
      def __init__(self):
          self.inventory = {}
          self.hp = 100
          self.fp = 50
          self.moves_history = []
          self.location = None
          self.is_turn = True



      def locate(self, room):
           self.location = room

      def attack(self, enemy, attack_type):
           if self.fp > attack_type.cost:
                 enemy.hp = enemy.hp - attack_type.value
      ...
```

This class can be read as "A player is an object with an inventory, hp, fp, a moves history, .. etc, and can be located and can attack"

And let's say you have a game or a match that runs and spawns a player in a room, with an item inventory and such.

```
Class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player()
        self.player.inventory = Inventory()
        self.player.locate(Room())
    ...
```

This says "a game is made of a player with an inventory, and located in a room".

Where Player, Inventory and Room are classes.
When instantiated as Player(), what is executed is their `__init__` method, you can read more about that method in the python docs.

For example, we want to specify that the initial inventory is a simple wooden sword, then I would make the init method of Inventory to be like this:

```
Class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weapons = ["SIMPLE_WOODEN_SWORD"]
        self.clothing =[]
        self.key_items = []
        self.pots = 2

    def discard_weapon(self,item):
         if item in self.weapons:
              self.weapons.remove(item)
     ...
```

you can alter a class' attributes by using its methods... you have to build useful methods that capture the way you think a Room can change and the way a player and enemy can interact with a room, for example.

As to your last question, how you choose to structure your code is subjective and up to you, but there is no need to reinvent the wheel... There are industry standards that guide how to structure industry-grade code, as certain practices are known to lead to more controllable/predictable outcomes - for example, modular code, explicit interfaces between modules, etc., but there is also no silver bullet. When you show your code to another person for the first time, if you show them a single function that is 2000 lines of code their reaction is pretty predictable (they will hate you). It's going to be hard for that person to read the code as text, and untangle the problem domain logic (what you want your game to be like) from the solution domain (what you were able to implement with your knowledge). We want to build modular code, we probably want the code to be useful to explain to ourselves and to others how we think the problem through. OOP is kinda really good at that, and arrives naturally whenever the logic of a problem becomes complicated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I did find this to be helpful. I had been using classes to define the player and enemies, but was struggling to figure out how to use them to create rooms. This has given me some ideas as to how I can start forming solutions to my problems. I just want to clarify so I understand fully; OOP is useful for organizing your code and making it more modular, but it isn't necessary wrong not to use it, provided everything stays organized/readable?

Comment: @ReelBigFan sure, there even are programming languages without classes (say, c). at the end of the day, paradigms are there to help us and not the other way around. we choose them because they give us a mental framework and we vibe with them!

Answer (score 2):

## Some ideas that might help debulk your code:

- Store rooms in text files or possibly in text files in directories. This would allow you to modify room information and would be less bulky. For handling text files and directories I recommend the `os` module. This would also allow you to randomly generate and store rooms in the future.
- Store relative room locations and items in nested dictionaries. Below is an example from a text-based RPG I wrote with the help of RaspberryPi.

### Nested Dictionaries:

```
rooms = {
    'main room' : {
        'SOUTH' : 'pantry',
        'EAST' : 'living room',
        'ITEMS' : ['letter']
    },

    'pantry' : {
        'NORTH' : 'main room',
    },

    'living room' : {
        'WEST' : 'main room',
        'ITEMS' : ['Knife', 'Potion']
    }
}
```

### Begining code:

```
this_room = 'main room'
```

Starts in `main room`

```
while True:
    action = input ('> ').upper().split()
    print (action)
    duty = ' '.join (action [1:])
```

`duty` is all of the information after the first command, reformated into `str` using the `' '.join ()` method

### Location code

```
    if action [0] == 'GO':
        if duty in rooms[this_room]:
            this_room = rooms[this_room][duty]
        else:
            print (f'You can\'t go {duty.lower()}')
```

This part of the code is responsible for navigation. The code checks to see if the action desired is to move by looking for the keyword "go", and finally, it takes the second part of the message and looks for the direction to move, so if the user entered `> go south` they would be moved to the pantry.

### Item acquiring code:

```
elif action [0] == 'GET':
        if 'ITEMS' in rooms[this_room] and duty in rooms[this_room]['ITEMS']:
            inventory += [duty]
            del rooms[this_room]['ITEMS'][rooms[this_room]['ITEMS'].index(duty)]
            print (f'Current inventory: {", ".join(inventory).lower()}')
        else:
            print (f'{duty.title()} is not in this room')
```

Checks to see if `duty` is in `this_room`, then adds it to `inventory` and finally, deletes it from the `'ITEMS'` list by finding its location using `.index ()` and then `del` that location.

I hope one of these suggestions is helpful. Good luck!